# Ubuntu nast error => can't initialize libnet engine: libnet_check_iface() ioctl: No such device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, hack, wifi

al ejecutar

```
sudo nast -m -i eth0
```

En mi **Ubuntu 20.04** en **VirtualBox**, me salta este error

> Error: can't initialize libnet engine: libnet_check_iface() ioctl: No such device
>   Have you activate a non-loopback iface? (man ifconfig)
>   Maybe autodetection is failing, try with "-i interface"

Comment: Has logrado encontrar la solución??

Answer (score 0):

lo más probable es que tu tarjeta de red no se llame eth0 puede ser eth1
pero para estar seguro ingresa a la configuración del sistema y verifica el nombre correcto en las opciones de red, en mi caso era **enp1s0** si estas desde cable de red o wifi el nombre va a ser diferente para cada caso.
[image: desde configuración puedo ver el nombre de la tarjeta de red]

[image: también puedes visualizar el nombre desde el administrador de recursos o tareas]